# Problem reconciling a recurrence, $g(n)=\sin(n-1)g(n-2)$ with closed form

Tags: recurrence-relations, pochhammer-symbol

Consider the recurrence relation in the title and its solution by induction.

$$
\begin{align}
&g(n)=\sin(n-1)g(n-2),\quad g(0), g(1) \text{ given}\\
&g(2)=\sin(1)g(0)\\
&g(3)=\sin(2)g(1)\\
&g(4)=\sin(3)g(2)=\sin(1)\sin(3)g(0)\\
&g(5)=\sin(4)g(3)=\sin(2)\sin(4)g(1)\\
&...\\
&g(n_{even})=g(0)\prod_{k_{odd}}^{n-1}\sin(k)\\
&g(n_{odd})=g(1)\prod_{k_{even}}^{n-1}\sin(k)
\end{align}
$$

Not the most desirable form of solution, being in two parts, but it is correct as verified numerically by comparison with the recurrence for random values of $g(0,1)$.

Next, I tried to compare this with a closed form solution obtained from WolfranAlpha. That solution is given as

$$
g_n=(1+i)^ne^{(in^2)/4}\big(c_2(-1)^n+c_1\big)(e^{-2i};e^{-4i})_{\frac{n}{2}}
$$

where $c_{1,2}$ are arbitrary parameters (to be determined from $g_{0,1}$) and $(a;q)_n$ is the [*q*-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol), which is defined as

$$
(a;q)_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-aq^k)=(1-a)(1-aq)(1-aq^2)...(1-aq^{n-1})
$$

which leaves me flummoxed by the $\frac{n}{2}$ in the WA solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: WA uses the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol#Identities)
$$
(a;q)_n=\frac{(a;q)_{\infty}}{(aq^n;q)_{\infty}},
$$
valid for $n\in \mathbb N$, to extend the definition of the $q$-Pochhammer symbol to $n\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks for that. At least it clarifies the solution. That said, I've tried some sample calculations. I have found that the products do not converge because $a$ and $q$ are complex. Beyond that, I'm not at all familiar with the *q*-Pochhammer symbol and may have to forgo the comparison I was seeking.